# Cannot read property 'collectionName' of undefined when filtering hasMany relationship

Tags: mongodb, adonis.js

I'm using **adonis.js/lucid ^6.1.3** with **lucid-mongo ^3.1.5** library to manage mongodb database. I need to build a query and filter a hasMany relationship but it throws an exception **Cannot read property 'collectionName' of undefined**

I've created a model called User and then provided a relation called session which must return all user sessions (Mobile or web session). I've used the approach described in adonis.js lucid relationship for querying data of relationships

```js
return await user.sessions().where({
    'logged_in_at': { $type: 10 },
    'logged_out_at': { $type: 10 }
}).where('tries', '<', 3).firstOrFail();
```

The expected output should be a session document (row) but this is the exception it throws **Cannot read property 'collectionName' of undefined**

Comment: I found that the method **first** works. The only difference in code between these two methods is only a **if clause**. Still don't know why **firstOrFail** does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstOrFail is a <s>static</s> method, which I believe means that you cannot use it with the query builder (I could be wrong). Instead, I'd try something along the lines of

```
return await user.sessions().where({
  ...
}).andWhere('tries', '<', 3').first()
```

first is a helper method on the query builder <s>and you have to call fetch when using the query builder with lucid models.</s>

EDIT: for some reason in the Adonis docs, it labels find and first/firstOrFail as static but they are not. [reference](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_static_methods)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm afraid to say that according to the source code of LucidMongo, both `first()` and `firstOrFail()` methods in QueryBuilder class are not static.You could review here: [GitHub](https://github.com/duyluonglc/lucid-mongo/blob/5717933f45e6d5f599ccd50a77c09a1f2282e553/src/LucidMongo/QueryBuilder/index.js#L326). Am I Correct?

Comment: @ErisRayanesh [Adonis Docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_static_methods). I was basing the code off of this. I've used the api a bit more and edited my answer with what I think would work. I originally called .fetch() after first(), but don't think that's necessary.

Comment: Absolutely your code works and I just said that these methods are both declared non-static. Please check my comment over my own question.  The only difference in code between these two methods is just a **if clause**.

Comment: @ErisRayanesh yea you are right it's not declared static. I wonder why in the adonis docs they call them "Static Methods". Also have you seen whether or not the compiled version of your code with 2 where clauses is different than mine that uses the andWhere? Look at this example with [andWhere](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-where). Also if my answer is correct could you mark it as the solution?